# Webpack - not finding module without running dev server

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can I get the webpack to bundle modules without running dev-server. When I run the command everything works fine, but when I just open the html file by clicking on it in my folder I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ajax"
>       at webpackMissingModule (app.js:76)
>       at Object. (app.js:76)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at app.js:66
>       at app.js:69

Since, I would like to put my project on github pages, I am going to need to able to run it without webpack server. How can I do that, and why I am getting this error?

This is the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './assets/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand that webpack-dev-server builds your code and stores in the memory. Meaning, it can only be accessible during run-time and is only advisable for development (as the name suggests).

If you want to make a production build, you need to make a script for it that will create an actual copy of the build. Then you can run it by opening the entry point from the build directory.

Comment: Thanks, so basically only adding this line to package.json solved it: ```"build": "webpack"```